Reasoning behind failure of string constraint in acceleration but not velocity
As I understand it, the string constraint used in mechanics with an ideal string is derived from the fact that the length of string always stays the same (provided it is under tension and not slack).
So, if the two ends of a string are labelled $A$ and $B$ and have velocities $v_a$ and $v_b$ along the string, from the string constraint ($\frac{dL}{dt} = 0$) we get $v_b = -v_a$.
Upon differentiating the above relation, we obtain: $a_a = -a_b$
This is purported to work for all string systems, regardless of how complex, because in no system does the length of an inextensible string change.
However, I recently came across a question wherein the accelerations of the ends of a string along the string appear to be different, seemingly implying elongation of an inextensible string. That is, the ends of the string have different accelerations along the string.
This is not a homework problem I need help with, rather a conceptual doubt as to the validity of the string constraint for systems with non-trivial motion.
Consider the setup shown (minimum reproducible example of such a system):

Where the acceleration of A is $a$ (straight downwards), acceleration of B is $b$, and B is constrained to move only along the surface it is placed on. Note that the string is massless and inextensible, friction is absent everywhere.
The question asks to find $b$ as a function of $a$, $\theta$ and $L$.
The intended solution is to find the relation between $v_a$ and $v_b$ and differentiate said relation w.r.t. time to find $b$.
A short summary of the working is as follows:
Method 1
Since the component of $v_b$ along the string = $v_a$ ($\Delta$length of string = 0)
$$v_a = v_b\cos\theta.$$
Differentiating w.r.t. time,
$$a = b\cos\theta - v_b\sin\theta \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
Since $v_b$ is along the plane, it follows that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{v_b\sin\theta}{L}.$$
Hence, finally, we obtain the following:
$$a = b\cos\theta - \frac{v_b^2\sin^2\theta}{L}$$
Method 2
If we are to solve the problem by assuming accelerations along the string:
Acceleration of A along string = acceleration of B along string
(Length of string constant -> $\mathrm{d}^2L_\text{str}/\mathrm{d}t^2 = 0$, string is always taunt)
$$a = b\cos\theta$$
which is also supported using tension constraint ($\sum{(T*A)} = 0$).

If we are to take the first method as correct, then the string's length seems to be changing, as the component of $b$ along the string $=/=$ component of $a$ along the string.
Why does the length of the string appear to be changing in this situation? Why is $a_a != a_b$ ?
Credits: Question appears at 01:16:00 in this video.

Hi Codeman. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the homework-and-exercises tag, and the Phys.SE policy for homework-like problems.

@Qmechanic thanks, I've re-added the homework tag. Is the question still considered off topic? I've elaborated on the area where my confusion stems from, as well as my reasoning for why it should be correct.

$v_a=v_b \cos \theta$ is correct, since the length of the string is constant. But if you use this to infer that $a_a = a_b \cos \theta$ then you are implicitly assuming  that $\theta$ is constant, which it is not.

@gandalf61 $v_a = v_bcos\theta$ is also derived by differentiating $x$ of both ends of the string, and holds. Why is it that the same does not hold for acceleration?

Basically the acceleration of $A$ is the second derivative of $L$. If you think about giving the block $B$ a constant velocity $v_B$, it is clear that $\dot{L}$ will not be constant, as for $L\rightarrow\infty$ it will be $\dot{L}\approx v_B$, while when the block $B$ is exactly under the pulley you will have $\dot{L}=0$.
If you calculate the variation of $L$ only due to a constant velocity $v_B$ (its second derivative in particular) you get exacly the correction term.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
